# render a blank view in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view

i need to prevent a view to be rendered in a specified case but i can't understand how to prevent it to render.

I tried

```
$this->autoRender=false
```

but nothing happened, probably because i'm using an API engine that manage rendering differently from regular controllers. Anyone know any trick to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Using `$this->layout = 'ajax'` does not seem to be enough.

But using these both lines works:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax'; 
$this->render(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

While searching for a solution, I found this answer. Now when using CakePHP 2.4.x, you could use the following code in your controller:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

This will lead to just the view being rendered, without a layout.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question. The current cake-version is 3.x and there is a easy way to use a blank layout.

Only add the in the controller:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->autoLayout(false);
```

Comment: Still tries to search for a view file and shows me `Error: The view for ExampleController::myAction() was not found`

Comment: You need to put `$this->viewBuilder()->autoLayout(false);` inside the action (or inside the initialize-method of the controller).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use ajax layout `$this->layout = 'ajax'` this is the default empty layout, which is used for ajax methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function function_without_layout(){ 
    $this->viewBuilder()->autoLayout(false);
    echo "hello Brij";
    exit;
}
```

`$this->layout = false;` is deprecated in CakePHP version 3.
Use `$this->viewBuilder()->autoLayout(false);` for CakePHP version 3.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your controller:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

This works in my project.

Answer (score 1):

The CakePHP 3 `autoLayout(false)` method from the other answer will still have the system try to locate a corresponding view/template file for the action you're calling. Since I needed no output at all, this didn't work for me, so I needed to also render an empty template.

Creating a blank `.ctp` file for every empty action you might need isn't an option really, because you'd normally want to have one and reuse it. CakePHP 2 had a `$this->viewPath` property which would let you configure the controller to look into the `app/View` folder, but it's CakePHP 3 alternative still looks into the corresponding controller and prefix folders. There is a not-so-obvious way to force CakePHP3 to look for a template in a root view path.

1. Create `src/Template/my_blank_view.ctp`
2. Add the following to your controller action:

   ```
   $this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
   $this->viewBuilder()->templatePath('.'); // this
   $this->viewBuilder()->template('my_blank_view');
   ```

Also, I'm using `$this->viewBuilder()->layout(false)` instead of `autoLayout(false)` because the latter kind of implies that there might be another layout set later, where the `layout(false)` just explicitly sets that there's no layout needed.

Comment: It is always nice to randomly google your own answer

Answer (score 0):

without knowing anything about API engine you're using, maybe try to make empty layout with empty content and call it in controller as `$this->layout = 'empty_layout'`